# Highcharts tooltip background according to line

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to make the tooltip's background color match the line's color using Highcharts.

I'm trying to find the most reasonable native way to handle this -- if it's possible to avoid adding a `<div />` with a background color to the formatter, that would be great - but if not I guess that works too.

The lines colors & amount will change a lot so I don't wanna hard-code the background colors the same way I put the line colors - if they could draw the background the same as the line color, that would be great.

My only idea didn't work, I'm not sure what the scope for these functions is in this case:

```
tooltip : {
    backgroundColor: function() {
        return this.line.color;
        //return this.point.color;
    }
}
```

My line colors are set normally:

```
series : [
    {
        color : '#fa0'
    }
]
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not possible to set this in other way than using formatter. Only something like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/GGQ2a/2/

JS:

```
tooltip: {
        useHTML: true,
        backgroundColor: null,
        borderWidth: 0,
        shadow: false,
        formatter: function(){
            return '<div style="background-color:' + this.series.color + '" class="tooltip"> ' +
                    this.series.name + '<br>' + this.key + '<br>' + this.y +
                '</div>';
        }
    },
```

And CSS:

```
.tooltip {
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px; 
}
```

Comment: The css is not getting applied in my case. Is there a sequence to write the css here ? Thanks !

Comment: Could you recreate issue on jsfiddle? As you can see, my demo works fine - make sure you have set all options properly.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without setting backgroundColor to null? This be default removes the pointer arrow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42772038/highcharts-tooltip-background-according-to-line-without-setting-backgroundcolor

Answer (score 1):

You can also try too hook up to `mouseOver` event.

Advantage of this solution over the one of Paweł Fus is that you can keep the width of tooltip which is necessary for nice anchor thing.

Reference:
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.events.mouseOver

```
 plotOptions: {
        series: {
            stickyTracking: false,
            events: {
                mouseOver() {
                    const color = arguments[0].target.color;

                    this.chart.tooltip.options.backgroundColor = color; //first time overwrite
                    const tooltipMainBox = document.querySelector(`g.highcharts-tooltip path:last-of-type`);
                    if (tooltipMainBox) {
                      tooltipMainBox.setAttribute('fill', color);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ymdLzzkb/1/

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but an alternate way to do this is to hook the `tooltipRefresh` event and swap in with some `jquery`.  Working code:

```js
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type:'column',
            events: {
            tooltipRefresh: function(e) {
              if (!e.target.hoverSeries) return;
              $('.highcharts-tooltip>path:last-of-type')
                .css('fill', e.target.hoverSeries.color);
            }
          }
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },
        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
        },{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
        },{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
        }]
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```