# highlight area chart lines when crossed in highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Im having an area which i have created using highcharts. The problem that im having is when the line crosses over another it becomes lighter in color.. how do i keep the line color the same or when i hover over the line to highlight and show it without making it lighter.

and how do i change the tooltip color to match the line color?

[image]

Below is my code

```
$(function () {
  var marker = {
        radius: 4,
        fillColor: '#FFFFFF',
        lineWidth: 2,
        symbol: 'circle',
        lineColor: null // inherit from series
      };

  var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    credits: { enabled: false },
    chart: {
      renderTo: 'container',
      type: 'area', 
      width: 600,
      height: 400
    },
    title: { text: 'Title', x: -20 //center
            },
    subtitle: {text: 'Subtitle', x: -20 },
    //title: { text: null },
    xAxis: {
      categories: [
          'NOV 11' ,
          'DEC 11' ,
          'JAN 12' ,
          'FEB 12' ,
          'MAR 12' ,
          'APR 12' ,
          'MAY 12' ,
        ],
        gridLineColor: '#DCEBEF',
        gridLineWidth: 0.5,
        lineColor: '#ffffff',
        lineWidth: 1
        //gridLineDashStyle: 'dash'
    },
    legend: {
      enabled: false
    },
    yAxis: {
      title: {
        text: null
      },
      gridLineColor: '#DCEBEF',
      lineColor: '#ffffff',
      lineWidth: 1,
      gridLineDashStyle: 'dash'
    },
    tooltip: {
      formatter: function() {
          return this.y;
      },
        backgroundColor: 'Grey',
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: '#AAA',
        style: {
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            color: 'White'
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
      area: {
        fillOpacity: 0.08
      }
    },
    series: [{
      name: null,
      lineWidth: 2,
      color: '#FA918C',
      marker: marker,
      data: [ 500, 500, 800, 1500, 1250, 800, 1150,],
        zIndex: 2,
        fillColor: {
                    linearGradient: [0, 0, 0,250],
                    stops: [
                        [0, 'rgba(250,145,150,0.5)'],
                        [1, 'rgba(255,255,255,0.5)']
                    ]
                }
    },
    {
      name: null,
      lineWidth: 2,
      color: '#674313',
      marker: marker,
      data: [ 1500, 500, 800, 1500, 1050, 1800, 150,],
        zIndex: 2,
        fillColor: {
                    linearGradient: [0, 0, 0,250],
                    stops: [
                        [0, 'rgba(250,145,150,0.5)'],
                        [1, 'rgba(255,255,255,0.5)']
                    ]
                }
    },
      {
      name: null,
      lineWidth: 2,
      color: '#87BCC2',
      marker: marker,
      data: [ 700, 950, 1100, 2000, 1650, 900, 1250,],
      zIndex: 1,
      fillColor: {
                    linearGradient: [0, 0, 0, 250],
                    stops: [
                        [0, 'rgba(135,188,194,0.5)'],
                        [1, 'rgba(255,255,255,0.5)']
                    ]
                }
    }
      ]
  });
});
```

Here is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tyz25j1p/3/

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First question, @davcs86's answer is good if you want to bring them out on mouseover, but if you don't want the lines obscured at all, you'd have to split them into a seperate series and `zIndex` them after the area series.

Second question, an easier way to set the background color could be to hook the tooltipRefresh event and set it based on the hovered series:

```
chart: {
      renderTo: 'container',
      width: 600,
      height: 400,
      type: 'area',
      events: {
        tooltipRefresh: function(e) {
          if (!e.target.hoverSeries) return;
          $('.highcharts-tooltip>path:last-of-type')
            .css('fill', e.target.hoverSeries.color);
        }
      }
    }
```

---

Working code here:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="jquery@3.0.0" data-semver="3.0.0" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container" style="height: 400px; width: 600"></div>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      var marker = {
        radius: 4,
        fillColor: '#FFFFFF',
        lineWidth: 2,
        symbol: 'circle',
        lineColor: null // inherit from series
      };

      var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        credits: {
          enabled: false
        },
        chart: {
          renderTo: 'container',
          width: 600,
          height: 400,
          events: {
            tooltipRefresh: function(e) {

              if (!e.target.hoverSeries) return;

              $('.highcharts-tooltip>path:last-of-type')
                .css('fill', e.target.hoverSeries.color);
            }
          }
        },
        title: {
          text: 'Title',
          x: -20 //center
        },
        subtitle: {
          text: 'Subtitle',
          x: -20
        },
        //title: { text: null },
        xAxis: {
          categories: [
            'NOV 11',
            'DEC 11',
            'JAN 12',
            'FEB 12',
            'MAR 12',
            'APR 12',
            'MAY 12',
          ],
          gridLineColor: '#DCEBEF',
          gridLineWidth: 0.5,
          lineColor: '#ffffff',
          lineWidth: 1
            //gridLineDashStyle: 'dash'
        },
        legend: {
          enabled: false
        },
        yAxis: {
          title: {
            text: null
          },
          gridLineColor: '#DCEBEF',
          lineColor: '#ffffff',
          lineWidth: 1,
          gridLineDashStyle: 'dash'
        },
        tooltip: {
          formatter: function() {
            return this.y;
          },
          backgroundColor: 'Grey',
          borderWidth: 1,
          borderColor: '#AAA',
          style: {
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            color: 'White'
          }
        },
        plotOptions: {
          area: {
            fillOpacity: 0.08
          }
        },
        series: [{
          name: null,
          lineWidth: 0,
          marker: {
            enabled: false
          },
          color: '#FA918C',
          type: "area",
          data: [500, 500, 800, 1500, 1250, 800, 1150, ],
          zIndex: 2,
          fillColor: {
            linearGradient: [0, 0, 0, 250],
            stops: [
              [0, 'rgba(250,145,150,0.5)'],
              [1, 'rgba(255,255,255,0.5)']
            ]
          }
        }, {
          name: null,
          lineWidth: 0,
          color: '#000000',
          type: 'area',
          marker: {
            enabled: false
          },
          data: [1500, 500, 800, 1500, 1050, 1800, 150, ],
          zIndex: 2,
          fillColor: {
            linearGradient: [0, 0, 0, 250],
            stops: [
              [0, 'rgba(250,145,150,0.5)'],
              [1, 'rgba(255,255,255,0.5)']
            ]
          }
        }, {
          name: null,
          lineWidth: 0,
          color: '#87BCC2',
          type: 'area',
          marker: {
            enabled: false
          },
          data: [700, 950, 1100, 2000, 1650, 900, 1250, ],
          zIndex: 1,
          fillColor: {
            linearGradient: [0, 0, 0, 250],
            stops: [
              [0, 'rgba(135,188,194,0.5)'],
              [1, 'rgba(255,255,255,0.5)']
            ]
          }
        }, {
          name: null,
          lineWidth: 2,
          color: '#FA918C',
          marker: marker,
          zIndex: 3,
          data: [500, 500, 800, 1500, 1250, 800, 1150, ]
        }, {
          name: null,
          lineWidth: 2,
          color: '#000000',
          type: 'area',
          marker: marker,
          data: [1500, 500, 800, 1500, 1050, 1800, 150, ],
          zIndex: 3,
        }, {
          name: null,
          lineWidth: 2,
          color: '#87BCC2',
          marker: marker,
          data: [700, 950, 1100, 2000, 1650, 900, 1250, ],
          zIndex: 3
        }]
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.toFront()` function

```
plotOptions: {
    area: {
        fillOpacity: 0.08,
        events: {
            mouseOver: function(e) {
                this.group.toFront();
                this.markerGroup.toFront();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For the tooltip, you can check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18742654/2423859)

**Example**

```js
$(function() {
  var marker = {
    radius: 4,
    fillColor: '#FFFFFF',
    lineWidth: 2,
    symbol: 'circle',
    lineColor: null // inherit from series
  };

  var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    credits: {
      enabled: false
    },
    chart: {
      renderTo: 'container',
      type: 'area',
      width: 600,
      height: 400
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Title',
      x: -20 //center
    },
    subtitle: {
      text: 'Subtitle',
      x: -20
    },
    //title: { text: null },
    xAxis: {
      categories: [
        'NOV 11',
        'DEC 11',
        'JAN 12',
        'FEB 12',
        'MAR 12',
        'APR 12',
        'MAY 12',
      ],
      gridLineColor: '#DCEBEF',
      gridLineWidth: 0.5,
      lineColor: '#ffffff',
      lineWidth: 1
        //gridLineDashStyle: 'dash'
    },
    legend: {
      enabled: false
    },
    yAxis: {
      title: {
        text: null
      },
      gridLineColor: '#DCEBEF',
      lineColor: '#ffffff',
      lineWidth: 1,
      gridLineDashStyle: 'dash'
    },
    tooltip: {
      formatter: function() {
        return this.y;
      },
      backgroundColor: 'Grey',
      borderWidth: 1,
      borderColor: '#AAA',
      style: {
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        color: 'White'
      }
    },
    plotOptions: {
      area: {
        fillOpacity: 0.08,
        events: {
          mouseOver: function(e) {
            this.group.toFront();
            this.markerGroup.toFront();
          }
        }
      }
    },
    series: [{
      name: null,
      lineWidth: 2,
      color: '#FA918C',
      marker: marker,
      data: [500, 500, 800, 1500, 1250, 800, 1150, ],
      fillColor: {
        linearGradient: [0, 0, 0, 250],
        stops: [
          [0, 'rgba(250,145,150,0.5)'],
          [1, 'rgba(255,255,255,0.5)']
        ]
      }
    }, {
      name: null,
      lineWidth: 2,
      color: '#000000',
      marker: marker,
      data: [1500, 500, 800, 1500, 1050, 1800, 150, ],
      fillColor: {
        linearGradient: [0, 0, 0, 250],
        stops: [
          [0, 'rgba(250,145,150,0.5)'],
          [1, 'rgba(255,255,255,0.5)']
        ]
      }
    }, {
      name: null,
      lineWidth: 2,
      color: '#87BCC2',
      marker: marker,
      data: [700, 950, 1100, 2000, 1650, 900, 1250, ],
      fillColor: {
        linearGradient: [0, 0, 0, 250],
        stops: [
          [0, 'rgba(135,188,194,0.5)'],
          [1, 'rgba(255,255,255,0.5)']
        ]
      }
    }]
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px; width: 600"></div>
```